# How to save overwatered, deleaved bonsai?

Tags: trees, plant-health, leaves, tree-care, bonsai

Let me start off with I know what I did to damage it, and looking to find out if I can undo it.

[image: sad tree ):]

Long story short, I was an idiot and left my very happy Fukien Tea in the rain. I came back to everything soaked, brown, and falling off. It's got like seven leaves left of its former glory and while they're fully green now, I worry about their future. Is there any way to reverse this or am I going to have to start over?
(This is tree before for reference)

[image: happier tree]

Comment: With proper drainage rain or over watering shouldn't be that devastating. What kind of rain was it? Very cold weather rain? Was there frost in the night? How often is it fertilized and/or repotted?

Comment: It was a heavier rain, but it wasn't too cold, in the 60s, no frost. I've never repotted it as I've only had it 6 months and I just started to fertilize it every couple weeks as summer is starting

Comment: I am still not convinced that rain and over watering is the problem. Your pot seems to be a real one, so it should have a drainage hole. So surplus water would leave after rain. I don't know your climate, but 60F is too low for a tropical bonsai. This species is tropical and should only be outdoor when temp. > 68F (20C). If lower it should be kept indoors. My guess is that the tree is suffering from cold instead of too much water.